# Python: How to combine two dataframes, while summing rows with identical indices and keeping unique ones?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different sizes (row-wise):

```
df1:
         col1  col2  col3  col4   ...
index1   a11   a12   a13   a14
index2   b11   b12   b13   b14
index4   c11   c12   c13   c14
index5   d11   d12   d13   d14


df2:
         col1  col2  col3  col4   ...
index1   e11   e12   e13   e14
index2   f11   f12   f13   f14
index3   g11   g12   g13   g14
index5   h11   h12   h13   h14
index6   i11   i12   i13   i14
```

Note, the column names in both dataframes are identical and there can be several thousand of them. The values a11-i14 are arbitrary integers. The indices are my ID's (integers). A large portion of them from df1 are identical with the ones in df2 (here: index1, index2 and index5) but not all of them. Both dataframes can contain unique indices. The indices in both dataframes are ordered.

I want to create a new dataframe "df3" which looks like this:

```
df3:
         col1      col2      col3      col4
index1   a11+e11   a12+e12   a13+e13   a14+e14
index2   b11+f11   b12+f12   b13+f13   b14+f14
index3   g11       g12       g13       g14
index4   c11       c12       c13       c14
index5   d11+h11   d12+h12   d13+h13   d14+h14
index6   i11       i12       i13       i14
```

I want to combine df1 and df2 in such a way, that rows with identical indices are summed (in this case index1, index2, index5). Otherwise, the unique rows are to be added unchanged. The order of the indices/rows is important.

How can I do that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: probably some kind of `join` with `sum` in there somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `add`:

```
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

or `concat` followed by `groupby`:

```
pd.concate([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Comment: Well, this was kind of anticlimactic^^. I tried diffferent things with `join` and `merge` and failed. Thank you very much! `Add` did the trick just fine.